# Git cloning a framework with submodules

Tags: git

I currently have the following situation.
I have a private project that acts like a framework that I wanna use as the base for a range of other projects. In the root of the project there are a few folders named themes, modules, plugins and some more that were made to make unique changes too. When the clone is made, the main goal is to update and add content to these sub-folders.

```
framework/
 | - config.ini
 | - core.c
 | - module_handler.c
 | - plugin_handler.c
 | - theme_handler.c
 | - modules/
 | - plugins/
 | - public/
      | - images/
 | - themes/
```

- I want to be able to **update the framework** version in each clone. (**important**)
- I want the **framework in the root directory** of the clone. (**important**)
- I want the **ability to pick commits/changes in the clone and push them back to the framework** sometimes. (would be nice, but I could live with the pain of doing it manually)
- **I most not use branches.** They are clearly separated.

I've been reading a whole day about submodules and I feel that concept would have been perfect. Except that it seems they can not live within the root of a new project, since the .git folder is obviously colliding. But I don't know how I would handle it if it can't be in the root directory. Is there any hack or something I can use?

If I can't get everything, I could live without the ability to easy merge back changes to the framework.

I'm making the assumption that I will always work alone on this thing. I just want it more organized and self-explained for myself.

What is the best way to tackle this problem and achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

```
git add .
(addig every changes to repo)

git push master master
(update the whole master)
```

Comment: So that's a normal clone of the framework? That is pushing back and forth commits to the real framework?

Comment: If the branch contaion it or the git url correct, yes, you can clone it.